# FIR filter and the relation between Sample rate and cut-off frequency

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I have problem to unterstand the logic of the cut-off frequency of the FIR filter. 
Suppose my sample rate is 2MHz and I want to design a lowpass filter with a cut-off frequency 100Hz. What will be $\omega_c$ below:

LowpassFilter[data,$\omega_c$,n]

and what is the limit on kernel "n"?

Comment: Under `Details and Options` in the docs: "With SampleRate->r, the cutoff frequency Subscript[\[Omega], c] should be between 0 and r*\[Pi]." So I always just specify sample rate then use the cutoff I want times Pi. `LowpassFilter[data,100*\[Pi],n,SampleRate->2*10^6]` will filter a 2MHz signal at 100Hz. An audio example is also shown in the docs. There isn't any info in the docs, but it looks like the limit on the kernel is `Length@data`, it doesn't complain if n is larger, but it doesn't change the answer.